# OpenCV: Trying to create an blank image but core has been dump

Tags: c++, opencv

i m trying to preform a task using opencv c++ and the task is i am trying to create an blank image using opencv c++ whose background is white. Here is my code:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
 Mat img = imread("/home/jordan/opencv/Test/taskb/img.bmp");
 Mat img2;
 int i,j;
 for(i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
 {
  for(j=0;j<img.rows;j++)
  {
    int Red=img.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2];
    int Green= img.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1];
    int Blue = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0];

   cout<<"cols="<<i<<"  rows="<<j<<"  Red="<<Red<<"  Green="<<Green<<"  Blue="<<Blue<<" \t\n";

  }
}

img2=img;

for(i=0;i<img2.rows;i++)
{
 for(j=0;j<img2.cols;j++)
 {
   if (img2.channels() == 3)
   {
      img.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2]=255;
      img.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1]=255;
      img.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]=255;
   }
 }
}



cout<<"cols="<<img.cols<<" row="<<img.rows<<"\n";
 namedWindow("Images",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
 namedWindow("Image2",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
 imshow("Images", img);
 imshow("Image2",img2);

 while(char(waitKey(1)) != 'q'){}

 return 0;

}
```

i am trying to execute above mention code but it is showing core dump     problem as mention below

```
*** Error in `./image': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x081da6e0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: memory corruption means that you're overwriting memory which doesn't belong to you somewhere (at or before the line which is triggering the crash). You might want to check that your indexes & loop limits are the correct way around (the 2 blocks you posted each try a different order).

Comment: valgrind and / or electric fence

Answer (score 0):

just use a constructor:

```
Mat img = imread(...);
Mat img2(img.size(), img.type(), Scalar::all(255));
```

also: you got rows and cols wrong

```
img.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2]=255; // should have been i,j
```

(as a general rule of thumb, - whenever you catch yourself writing per-pixel loops in opencv, you're doing it wrong)